# In AsciiDoc, how to link a Unix manpage?

Tags: man, asciidoc

Does stock AsciiDoc provide macros to link a Unix manual page? I'm thinking of something like `man:vim(1)`, equivalent to the command `man 1 vim`, similar to the standard URL and `link:` inline macros. If not, can AsciiDoc be taught to understand such links for example by configuring it?

Answer (score 3):

I think I found what I was looking for namely the inline macro `man` from [Asciidoctor's Extensions Lab](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-extensions-lab/tree/master/lib/man-inline-macro). Even though it is not part of stock AsciiDoc at least it is listed as one of the [Asciidoctor's Official Extensions](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/extensions/). With it one can express links to a manpage plus section like so `man:vim[1]`.

Comment: There is an [example](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoctor/latest/extensions/inline-macro-processor/) of how it can be included in your app.